# Incorrect window layout while resizing MessageBox on Windows

Tags: winapi, c++-cli, hook, messagebox

I have to change the button text/size of a standard MessageBox in Windows (Win 7 actually). I'm coding in C++/CLI so the only way to show such a window is to do `System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(...)`. I can modify the button by hooking a function to WH_CBT and getting the code HCBT_ACTIVATE...

So far so good. Now I want to resize the window itself to fit the buttons. I get the code HCBT_CREATEWND and I modify the struct CBT_CREATEWND (member `cx` for the width, etc.) And it works...

But it appears that the MessageBox buttons are drawn over a gray rectangle that spans the whole window width. This rectangle is not a window (using Spy++) but probably a draw done with FillRectangle() or something equivalent. **And unfortunately my procedure won't allow to redraw it.** In other words, if I widen the MessageBox, the gray rectangle under the buttons is not redrawn.

Here is my (oversimplified) function:

```
// Simplified code...
#define NEW_WIDTH 300
LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
    switch ( code )
    {
        case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
            // Change buttons here
            return 0;

        case HCBT_CREATEWND:
            // Change window size here
            LPCBT_CREATEWND cw = (LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam;
            if ( 'Main MessageBox Window, don't worry it works fine' )
            {
                cw.cx = NEW_WIDTH;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx( hook, code, wParam, lParam );
}
```

So my question is quite simple: how, using the hook mechanism, can I force the MessageBox to draw the gray rectangle under the buttons correctly when it is resized by a hook function?

Comment: Seems like it would be easier just to create your own MessageBox?

Comment: That is what I'm gonna do!

Comment: Also, for the record, I always though that gray background looked nice. :)

Comment: Just imagine what would happen were MS to change the appearance from version to version of the os. Oh wait, that's already happened multiple times.